# SearchObject/SearchResult Wrapper API for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, zk

I work on a big project using Hibernate, Spring and ZK frameworks, and I want to upgrade to Hibernate 5. There are several ZK tables with DB-layer paging/filtering/sorting in the GUI. For these tables we use the approach described in https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2009/May/Paging_Sorting_with_a_filter_object, that is, the model of the table has a SearchObject (wrapper of the query), a SearchResult (wrapper of the resultset) and a reference to the DAO. By paging/sorting/filtering the SearchObject will be changed, and then processed by the DAO automatically.

The problem is that the hibernate-generic-dao project (https://code.google.com/archive/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) is dead and should be upgraded to Hibernate 5. I consider to upgrade it myself (or at least the search and search-hibernate modules), but I am interesting whether there is a similar living project. (Although it would be painful to use a different API in each cases.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit similar to [spring-data repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) which greatly reduce boiler plate code, and provide a common interface for regular CRUD/Paging/Sorting repository methods. The implementation is generated automatically based on naming-conventions and meta-data.
At the same time it is extensible down to native queries in case none of the naming conventions match.
Also the [query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) functionality might be a candidate to replace your dynamic SearchObject.

Maybe that's something for you.